# PWA Magento2.3.5 Overwrite Logo Component in Custom Project

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.5, pwa, component

Magento PWA Docs for overwrite a component such as Footer is found here:https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/pwa-studio-fundamentals/modify-site-footer/

So I'm assuming the same steps should be taken to overwrite any other component such as Logo:

What've done ins my pwa-custom project!

in my project folder `pwa-custom`

`mkdir -p src/components/Logo`

`cp node_modules/@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/Logo/logo.js src/components/Logo`

For testing I've edited **logo.js** and added `console.log('here');`

Create a `src/components/Logo/index.js` file with the following content to set the default component export for the Logo directory.

`export {default} from './logo'`

on `yarn run watch`  no changes or compilation activates.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2):

Not so simple. One cannot overwrite `Logo` without first overwriting `Header` component:

**main.js**

```
return (
        <main className={rootClass}>
            <Header /> //Header imports Logo hence it need Header first!
            <div className={pageClass}>{children}</div>
            <Footer />
        </main>
    );
```

Same process to Overwrite Footer to follow for Header once Header has been overwritten the Logo overwrite will work!

Thanks